# ScrollView is not Working in ConstraintLayout and viewPage

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I am working with constraint layout I am trying to use scrollview within it, Especially when keypad occurs on screen. When keypad appears alignment completely changes and scrollview  doesn't appear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    tools:context=".Activity.HomeActivity">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:id="@+id/Constrain_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_gradient"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tabLayout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use linear layout inside the scroll View and keep your toolbar outside the scroll view. If you want the toolbar to disappear on scroll you should do it in right way!

Comment: Why are you using orientation property inside your constraint layout, that is not recommended!

Answer (score 0):

Use this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in activity tag in manifest

> Example:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
```

Comment: I have done this in manifest still I m not getting scroll bar